# How I can get view by id in my espresso tests?

Tags: java, android, view, android-espresso

I don't understand how I can get a view from the screen in my espresso tests with `findViewById.`

I'm going to one of a screen in my app with espresso autotest, and then I want to check the screen is correct. For that, I need to get toolbar from the screen and check some of his properties. 
First I tried to make this with `ViewInteractions` objects, but I can cast it into View and can't get access to object properties.

I want to use `findViewById` for getting a view directly, but I can understand how to use it right.

```java
public void goToMyOrders (){
        BottomTabBar bottomTabBar = new BottomTabBar();
        bottomTabBar.profileButton.perform(click());
        myOrderButton.perform(click());
        ViewInteraction toolbarView = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.custom_font_toolbar)));
        toolbarView.getContext();
        toolbarView.check(matches(withText("Мои заказы")));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Nah, I think you got an idea about testing a little wrong. Firstly, `Toolbar` doesn't extend/inherit `TextView`, so it can't have text, but you can place a `TextView` inside `Toolbar`. I've prepared simple code to show you an idea of automated tests using `Espresso`.

Create a new sample app, place this layout into your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/toolbar"
        android:text="SomeTextBeforeChange"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="Change text after click"/>
```

in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText("Changed text");
        }
    });
}
```

}

As you see this **might** be a similar `View` like yours -  `Toolbar`, `TextView` and `Button` which changes `TextView`'s text.

Let's make an automated test now using `Espresso`.

1. In your androidTest subfolder create a new Class, name it e.g `MainActivityTest`.
2. Define an `ActivityTestRule`. Read about it in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule)
   You may also need those `Gradle` dependencies:

   `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'`

   Rule:
   `@Rule
   public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<> 
   (MainActivity.class);`

   Then define a public method with return type void, annotated with `@Test`. 
   Inside this method you can define your `TextView` by calling `Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(your.textview.id));`

To check whether it contains specified text you need to call `textview.check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("expected text")));

I won't explain those methods what exactly do because their names speak for themselves, but if you had some troubles in understanding them you have plenty resources here on `StackOverflow`. To my code above, I wrote the following simple test, so you can analyse this if you want:

```
public class MainActivityTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void checkIfButtonChangesText(){
    // TextView
    ViewInteraction textView = Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.textview));
    // Button
    ViewInteraction button = Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.button));

    //check if TextView contains text: "SomeTextBeforeChange"
    textView.check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("SomeTextBeforeChange")));

    // analogically with Button, text: "Change text after click"
    button.check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("Change text after click")));

    // perform button click:
    button.perform(ViewActions.click());

    //Check if text has been changed to "Changed text"
    textView.check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("Changed text")));

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ViewAction to get view by findviewbyId in addition to ViewInteraction.

For YourCase it will be like:

```
Public View getView(int Rid) {
   onView(allOf(withId(Rid))).perform(new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isAssignableFrom(TextView.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "getting text from a TextView"; 
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view; 
        }
    });
    return tv
}
```

Note: I used textview as a constraint if for textview.You can use other constraints also from ViewMatchers